# Flink Time Window Start Time for 5 minute window

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

The start time of my 5 minute tumbling window seems incorrect.  The start time of the window and the current time are always 1 minute appart, but should be at least 5 minutes apart.

I am performing aggregation on a 5 minute tumbling window.  I store the aggregations into DynamoDB.  In the DynamoDB record, I store the window timestamp and the current time.  The window timestamp is always the last minute of the 5 minute window and the current time is always at the end of the window.  The current time seems correct, but the window timestamp should be 5 minutes before the end of the window.  The data that is being stored is correct, so I think I must be getting the window start time incorrectly.

I have the aggregation stream defined like:

```
 DataStream<> stream = inputStream
                        .keyBy(new KeySelector())
                        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5))
                        .aggregate(new Aggregator());
```

My Element Converter looks like:

```
public class DynamoDbAggregationConverter implements ElementConverter<Aggregation, DynamoDbWriteRequest> {

@Override
public DynamoDbWriteRequest apply(Aggregation agg, SinkWriter.Context context) {
    long startWindowTimestamp = context.timestamp();
    long createTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
.....
}
```

Comment: Note: This also happens for 1 hour windows.  The context timestamp and current time are 1 minute apart even though the window is 1 hour long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered The SinkWriter.Context does not have the window boundaries (I'm not sure what it is used for).

A ProcessWindowFunction is needed to get the window boundaries like described in the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#processwindowfunction).